# Three.js plane is hidden if the mouse is outside the browser

Tags: javascript, web, three.js

I am new to the three.js, i did an intro but i have a weird problem. While the mouse is outside the content (ex. i reload the page and cursor is on the reload button of the browser or outside the browser), the object is not visible. Can anyone suggest what is the problem.

Comment: Please post your code in jsfiddle so that we can help you find the problem.

Comment: @NickDeBeer here is the hsiddle file.
https://jsfiddle.net/L6c8dhxd/
Thnx anyway

Comment: I have updated your jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/L6c8dhxd/2/ Its using the latest three.js and stats.js library from a cdn. I don't see the problem you are having. Please elaborate if you see the error here.

Comment: on that file i have a logo which os set to a plane, when i run on the browser, the plane is not appearing if the mouse is not in the browser content, for example, the cursor is outside the browser, or if i refresh the page and the cursor is on the browser button, the animation and the plane is not appearing

Comment: I have to put cursor on the browser content in order the animation and the plane to appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that `mouseX` and `mouseY` are undefined when running `render()`. You are binding rotation to the mouse, however because you have not entered the screen, mouseX and mouseY are still undefined.

```
function render() {
    ....

    mesh4.rotation.x = mouseY;  //undefined here
    mesh4.rotation.y = mouseX;  //undefined here

    ...
}
```

and only on `onDocumentMouseMove()` will you give mouseX and mouseY a value

```
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) { 
    var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth/2;
    var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight;
    mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 11000; // <-- gets a value here
    mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 11000; // <-- and here
}
```

The **solution** is to set both variables to **0** on init(), so that they are not undefined when running the render() function.

```
function init() {
    mouseX = 0;
    mouseY = 0;

    ...
}
```

heres the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L6c8dhxd/3/

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked. Instead of setting mouseX and mouseY on the init(), i put 0 value on declaring globally. I am new, i have a lot of work to do to organize in a good way. Thank you again.